# Return a reference to a T inside a lazy static RwLock<Option<T>>?

Tags: rust, readwritelock, lazy-static

I have a lazy static struct that I want to be able to set to some random value in the beginning of the execution of the program, and then get later. This little silly snippet can be used as an example:

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::RwLock;

struct Answer(i8);

lazy_static! {
    static ref ANSWER: RwLock<Option<Answer>> = RwLock::new(None);
}

fn answer_question() {
    *ANSWER.write().unwrap() = Some(Answer(42));
}

fn what_is_the_answer() -> &'static Answer {
    ANSWER
        .read()
        .unwrap()
        .as_ref()
        .unwrap()
}
```

This code fails to compile:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/lib.rs:15:5
   |
15 |        ANSWER
   |   _____^
   |  |_____|
   | ||
16 | ||         .read()
17 | ||         .unwrap()
   | ||_________________- temporary value created here
18 | |          .as_ref()
19 | |          .unwrap()
   | |__________________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I know you can not return a reference to a temporary value. But I want to return a reference to `ANSWER` which is static - the very opposite of temporary! I guess it is the `RwLockReadGuard` that the first call to `unwrap` returns that is the problem?

I can get the code to compile by changing the return type:

```
fn what_is_the_answer() -> RwLockReadGuard<'static, Option<Answer>> {
    ANSWER
        .read()
        .unwrap()
}
```

But now the calling code becomes very unergonomic - I have to do two extra calls to get to the actual value:

```
what_is_the_answer().as_ref().unwrap()
```

Can I somehow return a reference to the static `ANSWER` from this function? Can I get it to return a `RwLockReadGuard<&Answer>` maybe by mapping somehow?

Comment: As you guessed, the example will not work because the reference returned (from the Option) is bound to the `LockGuard`, which is dropped at the end of the function. The borrow checker is preventing a reference to `ANSWER` from escaping from the lock. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @user2722968 I want to set a global variable when the program starts (based on some setting in a config file), and I want to be able to ergonomically access it later from various places in the program. Everything is happening in the same thread.

Comment: @user2722968 I edited to add some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.4.0/once_cell/) is designed for this: use `.set(...).unwrap()` in `answer_question` and `.get().unwrap()` in `what_is_the_answer`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your intention, the value of `Answer` can't be computed while it is being initialized in the `lazy_static` but depends on parameters known only when `answer_question` is called. The following may not be the most elegant solution, yet it allows for having a `&'static`-reference to a value that depends on parameters only known at runtime.

The basic approach is to use two `lazy_static`-values, one of which serves as a "proxy" to do the necessary synchronization, the other being the value itself. This avoids having to access multiple layers of locks and unwrapping of `Option`-values whenever you access `ANSWER`.

The `ANSWER`-value is initialized by waiting on a `CondVar`, which will signal when the value has been computed. The value is then placed in the `lazy_static` and from then on unmovable. Hence `&'static` is possible (see `get_the_answer()`). I have chosen `String` as the example-type. Notice that accessing `ANSWER` without calling `generate_the_answer()` will cause the initialization to wait forever, deadlocking the program.

```
use std::{sync, thread};

lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    // A proxy to synchronize when the value is generated
    static ref ANSWER_PROXY: (sync::Mutex<Option<String>>, sync::Condvar) = {
        (sync::Mutex::new(None), sync::Condvar::new())
    };
    // The actual value, which is initialized from the proxy and stays in place
    // forever, hence allowing &'static access
    static ref ANSWER: String = {
        let (lock, cvar) = &*ANSWER_PROXY;
        let mut answer = lock.lock().unwrap();
        loop {
            // As long as the proxy is None, the answer has not been generated
            match answer.take() {
                None => answer = cvar.wait(answer).unwrap(),
                Some(answer) => return answer,
            }
        }
    };
}

// Generate the answer and place it in the proxy. The `param` is just here
// to demonstrate we can move owned values into the proxy
fn generate_the_answer(param: String) {
    // We don't need a thread here, yet we can
    thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Generating the answer...");
        let mut s = String::from("Hello, ");
        s.push_str(&param);
        thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

        let (lock, cvar) = &*ANSWER_PROXY;
        *lock.lock().unwrap() = Some(s);
        cvar.notify_one();
        println!("Answer generated.");
    });
}

// Nothing to see here, except that we have a &'static reference to the answer
fn get_the_answer() -> &'static str {
    println!("Asking for the answer...");
    &ANSWER
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    // Accessing `ANSWER` without generating it will deadlock!
    //get_the_answer();

    generate_the_answer(String::from("John!"));
    println!("The answer is \"{}\"", get_the_answer());

    // The second time a value is generated, noone is listening.
    // This is the flipside of `ANSWER` being a &'static
    generate_the_answer(String::from("Peter!"));
    println!("The answer is still \"{}\"", get_the_answer());
}
```